# sql server cannot return right fulltext search result for excel document

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, full-text-search

I am using sql server 2008 ,and have started fulltext service,and install 2010 ifilter from microsoft for it also.

Then I have a table with a filestream column ,add create fulltext index for it. Everything is all right util the fulltext search for excel file. I have put some excel files into it, xls,or xlsx documents. when I start fulltext search,The excels don't come out even if they contains the word I am searching. It can work as I espect rarely. But the word and ppt documents don't have the problem.
  I know the excel file storing format is quit different from the word .But the result is so different. Help....

Comment: any news on that? have the same problem